# Show CPU core usage for parent process and its child processes

Tags: process, performance, cpu, cpu-usage

Is it possible to display **CPU core usage** just for a single process and its child processes on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean all processes started by some process (have the same parent PID)?

If you have `pgrep` you can filter all the processes with the same parent ID:

```
top -p $(pgrep -P 2069 -d,)
```

If not you can filter all process ids through `awk` and use them with `top -p`:

```
top -p $(ps -eo pid,ppid |awk '($2==2069){printf "%s%s",delim,$1; delim=","}')
```

Change `$2==2069` with the actual parent pid you want to track.

Comment: That would show information about a single core usage, wouldn't it?